# Django Rest_framework "Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field Process"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have encountered the error which I cannot solve when browsing towards my rest_framework api page.

The full error (Django Error) is :

```
 Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `process` on   
 serializer `ResultSerializer`.
 The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute     
 or key on the `Shop` instance.
 Original exception text was: 'Shop' object has no attribute 'process'.
```

It seems that the serializer trying to get a value in the field given in another serializer called ResultSerializer but could not found it. I have checked all the fields are all of them are correct.

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

class ResultSet(models.Model):
    process = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    subprocess = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Shop(models.Model):
    Establishment = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Suburb = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Postcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    State = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    Establishment_Type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=6, max_digits=12)
    longtitude = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=6, max_digits=12)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('Establishment',)

class EntirelyResult(models.Model):
    Result = models.ManyToManyField(Shop, related_name='fullresult')
    Status = models.ManyToManyField(ResultSet, related_name='status')
```

Here is my serializers.py

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from .models import Shop, ResultSet, EntirelyResult

class ResultSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ResultSet
        fields = ('process', 'subprocess')

class ShopSerializer(ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = Shop
       fields = ('__all__')

class ShopDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    Result = ResultSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    Status = ShopSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = EntirelyResult
        fields = ('Result', 'Status')
```

Here is my views.py

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
from .models import EntirelyResult
from .serializers import ShopDetailSerializer

class ShopDetailAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = EntirelyResult.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ShopDetailSerializer
```

Was there anything i miss to make the rest_framework properly?

Comment: additionally you might need to specify the source as shown here: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/5542#issuecomment-340166742

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You got a typo in you serializer `ShopDetailSerializer` should be:

```
class ShopDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    Result = ShopSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    Status = ResultSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

Edit:
EntirelyResult maps `Result` field to `Shop` and `Status` field to `ResultSet` while serializer initially mapped `Result` field to `ResultSet` and `Status` field to `Shop`

Comment: @Arount - The Status value and the Result value are reversed

Comment: Thanks for editing, but... by switching you just introduced again the OP issue